# Filter array and document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## Schema

```js
[
    {
        _id:"doc1",
        type:"SR",
        title:"...",
        description:"...",
        author:"5",
        posts:[
            {
                author:"1",
                title:"..."
            },
            {
                author:"2",
                title:"..."
            },
            {
                author:"1",
                title:"..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id:"doc2",
        type:"SA",
        title:"...",
        description:"...",
        posts:[],
        author:"5"
    }
]
```

Every Document will have type either `SA` or `SR`. If type is `SA` then `posts` will be an empty array, otherwise it'll non empty.

Now, i want to get document and array elements based on certain conditions.

- if type is `SA` and `authorId=5` then return the entire document.
- if type is `SR` then return the elements of posts where `authorId=1`

> When type is `SA` then i would like to get `title,description,..` of the document otherwise get the `posts` by filter.

## My Query

> Using mongoose

```js
Blog.find({
            $or: [
                {
                    $and: [
                        { type: "SA" },
                        { authorId:"5" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "posts.authorId": "1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            posts: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$posts",
                    as: "post",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$post.authorId", "1"]
                    }
                }
            }
        })
            .then(posts => {
                console.log(posts)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
```

## Returned document

```js
[
    {
        _id:"doc1",
        posts:[ 
            {
                author:"1",
                title:"..."
            },
            {
                author:"1",
                title:"..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id:"doc2",
        posts:[]
    }
]
```

#### How can i include other attribute of `doc2`?

Comment: You can project it with the filter like https://mongoplayground.net/p/4eoi049XBeY

Comment: @varman But, it'll also return the `title` and `type` of the post which does not have author = **5**

Comment: Ex: for `doc1` `title` and `type` is being returned, which is not intended

Comment: If you need to remove specific fields under some condition, then you need to go to aggregations. You mention you dont need other fields otherthan posts of type= "SR" ... when you map in mongoose, you can simple ignore those fileds no!! eventhouhgh those fields coming with all documents!

Comment: @varman i think i need to process all data at server after retriving from mongodb